# RectTransform.deltaSize not working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a selection menu code:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SelectionMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<MenuButton> buttons = new List<MenuButton>();
    public GameObject canvas;
    private Vector2 Mouseposition;
    private Vector2 fromVector2M = new Vector2(0.5f, 1.0f);
    private Vector2 centercircle = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    private Vector2 toVector2M;

    public int menuItems;
    public int CurMenuItem;
    private int OldMenuItem;
    private bool isDone = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        canvas.SetActive(false);
        menuItems = buttons.Count;
        foreach (MenuButton button in buttons)
        {
            button.sceneImage.color = button.NormalColor;
        }
        CurMenuItem = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GetCurrentMenuItem();
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
            ButtonAction();
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1) && !isDone)
        {
            canvas.SetActive(true);
            CrossHair.ok = true;
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.SetActive(false);
            CrossHair.ok = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            isDone = false;
        }
    }

    public void GetCurrentMenuItem()
    {
        Mouseposition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        toVector2M = new Vector2(Mouseposition.x / Screen.width, Mouseposition.y / Screen.height);
        float angle = (Mathf.Atan2(fromVector2M.y - centercircle.y, fromVector2M.x - centercircle.x) - Mathf.Atan2(toVector2M.y - centercircle.y, toVector2M.x - centercircle.x)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        if (angle < 0)
            angle += 360;
        CurMenuItem = (int)(angle / (360 / menuItems));
        if(CurMenuItem != OldMenuItem)
        {
            buttons[OldMenuItem].sceneImage.color = buttons[OldMenuItem].NormalColor;
            RectTransform oldTrans = buttons[OldMenuItem].sceneImage.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();


            oldTrans.sizeDelta = new Vector3(250, 250);
            Debug.Log("Resized: " + buttons[OldMenuItem].name);
            OldMenuItem = CurMenuItem;

            buttons[CurMenuItem].sceneImage.color = buttons[CurMenuItem].HighlightedColor;
            RectTransform newTrans = buttons[CurMenuItem].sceneImage.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            oldTrans.sizeDelta = new Vector3(280, 280);
        }
    }

    public void ButtonAction()
    {
        buttons[CurMenuItem].sceneImage.color = buttons[CurMenuItem].PressedColor;
        if(CurMenuItem == 0)
        {
            SetColor.color = buttons[CurMenuItem].HighlightedColor;
        }
        isDone = true;
    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class MenuButton
{
    public string name;
    public Image sceneImage;
    public Color NormalColor = Color.white;
    public Color HighlightedColor = Color.grey;
    public Color PressedColor = Color.gray;

}
```

Everything works as intended except one thing: the scaling does not work as intended. This line:

```
oldTrans.sizeDelta = new Vector3(280, 280);
```

this line runs only after I leave the highlighted selection (menuItem/Button)
and not when It starts highlighting. Its weird because one line before it I set the button to be highlighted and this line wont run until after its not highlighted anymore. also, this line:

```
oldTrans.sizeDelta = new Vector3(250, 250);
```

doesn't run at all. The Debug.Log that appears right after that line logs every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can't modify `sizeDelta` directly

`sizeDelta` tells you how much bigger or smaller this RectTransform is relative to its parent. In order to change this, you have to modify the anchors. If you are trying to set the RectTransform to have a size based on its content, then maybe [`SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors.html) is what you're looking for.